# How to swap datatables columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

So I'm getting data from an API.  This data has 13 different columns, but on my datatables table I only want to show 4 at a time.  To come up with a clean solution to this from a ux perspective, I built a dropdown where a user could select one of the 13 columns to switch the data with.  Unfortunately I can't see anyway to do this so please help.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Set all not visible columns to `visible:false` and make them visible when they're called upon.  Then make the column it's being switched with invisible
- `colReorder`
- clear the table, use jquery to modify the dom header to the correct title, then reinitialize the table with that column.  This didn't work because the data has to be in the same order as it was before the user swapped the column

Comment: DataTables has a `columns` key where you can retrieve the data using json so `{ "data" : "col1"` will retrieve the data where the key is `col1`. See more at https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data

Comment: How about building a different object that can be used by jQuery. This way you control what and how the data is to be displayed.

Comment: @A.Lau how do I put it in the new column though?

Comment: @jeff so just stop using datatables?

Comment: Easiest way is to just have `destroy: true` so you can just recreate as needed. See https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy

Comment: @A.Lau I actually solved this without doing that, by just setting the columns to visible then using colReorder.  I might get around to posting a solution one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the jQuery functions .hide and .show. The way I did this was by finding the index of the header title in that column. By for example:

```
(table).find('th').index($(table.find('th:contains(' + select + ')')))
```

Where select is your header title of the active or nonactive column.

Then with:

```
table.DataTable().column(j).visible(false);
```

You can hide that column, (visisble(true) to show that column). Where j is the index + 1, to account for the control column. It is a bit of hacking in the html, but it works.